# Meaning of “but” in the context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I was reading an article and ran into this phrase. Why “there is impact” is doubled in the end? Is it kind of emphasis of the phrase?

> In Western nations, there is much talk presently about the need for
> philosophy to “impact” wider societies. But there is impact and there
> is impact.

Comment: The question should be also be about the repetition of there is x.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

But there is impact and there is impact.

means: there are different kinds of impact.

This usage: But there is x and there is x. is used to emphasize they are differences between whatever the noun is. Not all x are the same.

It is not always used with "but" but here [oh boy] it is used to make the difference with the previous statement sharper.

Comment: different kinds or different levels: I said I owed you a favor but you’re asking me to pay off your house.  There’s favors and then there’s **FAVORS**.

Comment: @Jim Are you adding anything **NEW**?

Comment: I *thought* I was expanding your statement of different kinds to also include different levels.

Comment: When spoken, the two identical words are pronounced in different ways -- the last one will be stressed or in a different intonation pattern. Of course, this doesn't come through in print. Native readers will supply the intonation as they go along; English learners don't have this option.